# Titanium create basic Android TextField

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-android

There is a lot talking about creating borderless textfield in Android with Titanium. However, my question is a little bit different.

I want to create simple textField looks like editText in Android SDK. With Android SDK, I just need to place the EditText in screen without any other configuration, it will show blue border while focused and grey border otherwise.

In Titanium, if I do the similar approach, then it will show blue border when focused but no border if not focused.

Titanium Code:

```
var textField1 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    height: 50,
    width: 100,
    value: "Text 1",
    top: 100
});
self.add(textField1);

var textField2 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    height: 50,
    width: 100,
    value: "Text 2",
    top: 200
});
self.add(textField2);
```

Android Result:

[image: EditText with Android SDK]

Titanium Result:

[image: Titanium SDK]